# Interpreting the output of glm for Poisson regression

Tags: r, regression, glm, poisson

Consider the following:

```
foo = 1:10
bar = 2 * foo
glm(bar ~ foo, family=poisson)
```

I get results

```
Coefficients:
(Intercept)          foo  
     1.1878       0.1929  

Degrees of Freedom: 9 Total (i.e. Null);  8 Residual
Null Deviance:      33.29 
Residual Deviance: 2.399    AIC: 47.06
```

From the explanation on [this page](http://www.jerrydallal.com/LHSP/Poisson.htm), it seems like the coefficient of foo should be `log(2)`, but it's not.

More generally, I thought the output of this is supposed to mean that `lambda = 1.187 + .1929 * foo` where lambda is the parameter for the Poisson distribution, but that doesn't seem to fit with the data.

How should I interpret the output of this regression?

Comment: I think you're confusing differences and ratios. The exponentiated coefficient represents a multiplicative change (in expectation) not an additive one.

Comment: this isn't a programming question, really -- more of a stats question.  You can interpret the output as saying that the best-fit mean relationship is `lambda = exp(1.187 + 0.1929*foo)` (or if you prefer `lambda = exp(1.187)*exp(0.1929*foo)` -- `exp()` is the inverse-link function in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Poisson models are multiplicative. What this is saying is that as a result of some sort of averaging process that an increase of 1 in the order (increments in the `foo` predictor), will be associated with ratio of adjacent even integers in the range seq( 2, 20, by 2) that is exp(0.1929). I don't think the prediction is very good but when you look at the possible values, not bad.

```
> exp(0.1929)
[1] 1.212762

> seq(4,20,by=2)/seq(2,18,by=2) 
[1] 2.000000 1.500000 1.333333 1.250000 1.200000 1.166667 1.142857 1.125000 1.111111 
> mean( (2:11)/(1:10) )
[1] 1.292897
```